# Getting and setting maximum and minimum values from a Cartopy GeoAxesSubplot object

Tags: python, cartopy

I have an array of subplots that I would like to share a colorbar through a post-processing step. When plotting 1-d data, I can do this by iterating over the axes after creating the data and using get_ylims() and set_ylims() to find, and then set the correct global minimum and maximum values.

When working with Cartopy GeoAxesSubplot objects, however, I haven't been able to find functions to retrieve or set the z-axis limits. The function get_ylims corresponds to the plot rather than the data now.

I am trying to avoid taking the extra step to calculate vmin and vmax beforehand, because the processing for each subplot takes quite a long time and I would not like to do it twice. I would much rather adjust the geoaxes in a post-processing step.

Simply, how do I get from the first figure to the second figure if I am only given the first figure?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Create random data
data=[]
for i in range(4):
    data.append(i + np.random.random((10,10)))

# Plot with individual colorbars
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, subplot_kw={'projection':ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()})
for _ax,_dat in zip(ax.flat,data):
    im = _ax.imshow(_dat)
    plt.colorbar(im,ax=_ax)

fig.suptitle('Before.')
plt.show()

# Plot with a shared colorbar
fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, subplot_kw={'projection':ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()})
for _ax,_dat in zip(ax2.flat,data):
    im = _ax.imshow(_dat, vmin=0, vmax=4)

fig2.colorbar(im, ax=ax2.ravel().tolist())
fig2.suptitle('After.')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using the get_clim() and set_clim() functions of the matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh object.

I iterate over the axes, and then iterate over the components using get_children(). When I identify a QuadMesh object, I save it to a list. Finally, I iterate over that list twice, first to calculate the global minimum and maximum values, and then to set each subplot to those values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy as cpy
import matplotlib as mpl

geoaxes = figure.axes 

qms = [] # to store QuadMesh object
for i in geoaxes: # iterate over axes and find QuadMesh objects
    for j in i.get_children(): # breaks down a single axis (?) into components
        if isinstance(j, mpl.collections.QuadMesh):
            qms.append(j)

# Calculate global min and max values
min,max = qms[0].get_clim() # initialize min/max

for _qm in qms:
    _clim = _qm.get_clim()
    if _clim[0] < min:
        min = _clim[0]
    if _clim[1] > max:
        max = _clim[1]
    print(_clim)

# Set common bounds for each QuadMesh:
for _qm in qms:
    _qm.set_clim((min, max))
```